# Is the DEFLATE compression algorithm in ZIP and GZip formats based on LZ77 or LZSS?

Tags: zip, gzip, deflate, lz77, pkzip

Wikipedia states that the `DEFLATE` algorithm (used among others by the [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) and the [GZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) compression formats, but also by the [PNG image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG)) is based [on the LZ77 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77) :

> Deflate is a lossless data compression file format that uses a combination of LZ77 and Huffman coding.

LZSS' (a derivative of LZ77) [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski) on the other hand states that it's the main algorithm for various tools, including [PKZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP) (which uses the ZIP format, which uses the `DEFLATE` algorithm) :

> Many popular archivers like PKZip, ARJ, RAR, ZOO, LHarc use LZSS rather than LZ77 as the primary compression algorithm.

Similarly, [this GitHub page](https://github.com/daniel2643/LZSS-Compression) states that :

> LZSS algorithm can be used in many applications, such as gzip, PKZIP etc.

Like ZIP, the GZip file format also uses the `DEFLATE` algorithm.

And [here](https://ethw.org/History_of_Lossless_Data_Compression_Algorithms#DEFLATE) they state that :

> DEFLATE (...) combines an LZ77 or LZSS preprocessor with Huffman coding on the backend to achieve moderately compressed results in a short time.

So, if I understand correctly, `DEFLATE` can be based on either `LZ77` or `LZSS`. How is `DEFLATE` implemented today in the ZIP file format (used by PKZip) and the GZip file format ? Is it based on LZ77 or on LZSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LZ77 + Huffman. It's always been LZ77 in the generic sense. Wikipedia is wrong.

Deflate doesn't use LZ77 exactly as presented in the original paper, in that LZ77 always follows a match with a literal, whereas Deflate can follow a match with another match or a literal. This is still referred to as LZ77.

LZSS is a specific encoding of that variant on LZ77 that uses a one-bit prefix to decide on a literal vs. match. Deflate does not do that, instead using a single Huffman code for literals and lengths, where that is followed by a Huffman code for a distance if the previous code was a length.

Comment: I corrected the Wikipedia LZSS page and removed PKZIP from the list of archivers using LZSS.